# Compilation error - Tomcat, jsp

Tags: jakarta-ee, tomcat, compilation, javac

All,

I just installed apache tomcat and testing the installtion did show the "Successfully installed" apache page. I did execute the HelloWorld example without any issues. So now, I created my own web application under `\apache-tomcat-XXX\webapps\mine` with following 2 subfolders:

`\apache-tomcat-XXX\webapps\mine\classes`
`\apache-tomcat-XXX\webapps\mine\lib`

I created a new class file `HelloWorldAgain.java` with following contents:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

/**
 * My test servlet
 *
 * @author Liz Warner
 */

public class Hi extends HttpServlet {

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                      HttpServletResponse response)
        throws IOException, ServletException
    {
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Hola</title>");
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body bgcolor=\"white\">");
        out.println("<h1> Hi </h1>");
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
    }
}
```

However, when I compile the code from command line, I get errors related to

```
> Hi.java:4: package javax.servlet does not exist
import javax.servlet.*;
^
Hi.java:5: package javax.servlet.http does not exist
import javax.servlet.http.*;
^
Hi.java:13: cannot find symbol
symbol: class HttpServlet
public class Hi extends HttpServlet {
                        ^
Hi.java:15: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class HttpServletRequest
location: class Hi
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                      ^
Hi.java:16: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class HttpServletResponse
location: class Hi
                      HttpServletResponse response)
                      ^
Hi.java:17: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class ServletException
location: class Hi
        throws IOException, ServletException
```

I have set the following environement (Windows XP env.) variables:

JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_21
CATALINA_HOME: C:\Apache Tomcat\apache-tomcat-7.0.22

Comment: To get started with Java-ee, I highly suggest the latest Netbeans 7.0 EE edition, since it comes bundled with the Glassfish server. There are some official videos on Youtube about getting started.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Java class uses other Java classes that are not part of Java SE ("normal" or "desktop" Java) -- the Java EE classes in `javax.servlet` for example. So, the compiler doesn't know about them unless you tell it where to look for those classes. You need to find something like `javaee.jar` or `servlet.jar` -- Tomcat ought to contain them in its `libs/` dir, though I forget exactly what they are called.

Then you add them to your compile command with `javac -cp path/to/javaee.jar` ... for example.

This is really nothing specific to Tomcat or J2EE, it's just basic Java compiling.